# Sum columns in maM(marrayNorm) in R

Tags: r

I have to confess that I'm a *newbie* in R so, I really need some help here!

I have a `marrayNorm` object from library `marray` (on bioconductor), after the normalization of 12 arrays with 13640 spots each. Now I need to convert my 12 columns into 6 columns by sum together each 2 array normalized data columns .

start with `maM(marrayNorm)`:

```
 **a   b   c   d** ... (up to 12 columns)  
 1    2    3   4  
 5   6   7   8   
9   10  11  12
```

...13640 rows

end with:

```
**ab  cd**  
3   7  
11  15  
19  23
```

Comment: Should be trivial right? Just add columns 1,2 3,4 and 5,6? e.g.  `maM(mnorm)[,1]+maM(mnorm)[,2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
result <- cbind(maM(marrayNorm)[, 1] + maM(marrayNorm)[, 2],  
                maM(marrayNorm)[, 3] + maM(marrayNorm)[, 4], 
                maM(marrayNorm)[, 5] + maM(marrayNorm)[, 6],
                maM(marrayNorm)[, 7] + maM(marrayNorm)[, 8], 
                maM(marrayNorm)[, 9] + maM(marrayNorm)[, 10],
                maM(marrayNorm)[, 11] + maM(marrayNorm)[, 12])
```